# Drupal 7 View - How to show content based on conditions

Tags: views, entities, location

I've a travel portal and I've create a content type Destinations which I use to create content for main Destination page Continent, Countries, states and cities. This content type has uses Location module as a field.

Then I create a page e.g. Thailand which is of type Destinations.

I've create a block view to show the links to cities/countries/continents on country/continent/main destination pages.

So on my main Destination page I want to list all continents and countries, then on countries pages I want to list all states and cities, on state pages I want to show all cities.

Would it be possible to utilize the Location module to achieve this?

I'm using location to identify many type of content, e.g. Hotels, Places, Museums etc.

Or shall I use Taxonomy/Terms.

Or any other alternative ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to use hierarchical taxonomy tree, this would definitely make your life much easier when creating views listing child taxonomy terms or content tagged with child terms...

Comment: I agree that using taxonomy assignments to nodes about geographical "Destinations" would make this process easier than trying to use data from the location module. The location module works best when Views search results need to be sorted by proximity rather than the desired "boundary" of a country. Proximity search results can be to the user's current location or as a parameter (long/lat values) passed to the View.

Answer (score 0):

I dare to say that a simple text list (dropdown): City/Country/Continent/ etc would suffice, unless the tagging has to be open for public to add more terms.